# Need help in PHP. how to put restrictions?

Tags: php

I am currently working on a project where I have two pages: a login page and a home page. The home page is after the login page, whenever the user inputs his username and password correctly in the login page he will be directed to the home page. Here is the problem, if i input the url of the home page in the browser, it will open even if i did not go through the login page. How do i put restrictions in the home page? How do i put a message saying "you are restricted to access this page, please go back to login page" and then it redirects the user to the login page. If you know some website with tutorials or vidoes of tutorials please include them, it will be a great help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what sessions are for. You need to validate/authenticate your user before allowing them access to the home page.

On both your login and home pages, you need to start a session with this being at the very top of both scripts:

```
session_start();
```

Now when your user logs in successfully, you need to add a session value:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

Now in your home page, you need to authenticate that session.

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    die(header("Location: login.php"));
}
```

<sup>*The above code essentially says: `IF user session not set OR user session is empty -> KILL THE SCRIPT & GO TO THE LOGIN Page`*</sup>

Comment: I wrote almost exactly this and then checked the new answers. Thumbs up.

Comment: @IanThompson beat you by that much! :)

Comment: what does this mean " !isset($_SESSION['username'] "?

Comment: @marse sorry was a typo, fixed now. [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset). It essentially means, `IF(the $_SESSION['username'] IS NOT SET)`

Comment: tnx. how about the die? what does it mean?

Comment: @marse [`die()`](http://php.net/die) essentially kills the script right then and there so that no more processing of it is done.

Answer (score 0):

when your password and username is correct you must set a session.. in my case the session['logged_in'] = 1.

```
    if(!$_SESSION['logged_in'] == '1'){
      header('location:login.php'); 
      }else{
      //your home page..
     }
```

you must have a session... depending on your need.. I've used the mysql procedural... it's deprecated though.. just giving you the idea. =) you can either use PDO or mysqli... btw, put that code in your home.php page.

Comment: why is there a ! after $SESSION?

Comment: session is needed.. it's somewhat like a super global variable in which you can access in every php page.. just put the session_start(); before calling the session that you created.

Comment: it is reversing the output.. =) `!  = not`

Comment: or you can do `$_SESSION['logged_in'] != '1'`